# Jest - "Cannot log after tests are done." Having problems on import of functions

Tags: node.js, jestjs, sequelize.js

I recently came back to a test file and I'm getting an error that didn't used to appear. It's happening only when I import some functions for the tests:

```
const { _callXTimes, _itemFind, _chancePTFind, activityItemFind } = require('../../game/activities/activityItemFind');

There are no errors in the tests that use these functions... it's purely happening after I import this file. It also didn't used to cause this error.
```

The Error:
Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
Attempted to log "Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result".

```
  at CustomConsole.log (node_modules/@jest/console/build/CustomConsole.js:185:10)
  at Sequelize.log (node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:1094:23)
  at Query.run (node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:74:22)
  at node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:561:20
  at tryCatcher (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
  at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
  at Promise._settlePromise (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
  at Promise._settlePromise0 (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
  at Promise._settlePromises (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
  at _drainQueueStep (node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
```

Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

I have no idea why the test runner is getting hung up from file imports. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the test?

Comment: @h-sifat from my root, it's: __tests__/itemFind/itemFind.test.js

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar problem when running tests with Jest.

```
  ●  Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
```

Try this way as [Jest docs suggests.](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks#advance-timers-by-time) The takeaway is to use mock callback function.

Below codes will log: "log right away" and "log in two seconds" properly.

```
// at the top
jest.useFakeTimers()

// in describe block
    test.only("Should use fake timer", async function TestJestTimer() {
        const logInLog = (cb: () => void) => {
            console.log("log right away")

            setTimeout(() => {
                cb && cb()
            }, 2000);
        }

        const callback = jest.fn(() => console.log("log in two seconds"))

        logInLog(callback)

        expect(callback).not.toBeCalled()

        jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000)

        expect(callback).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    })
```

Result in terminal will be as followings.

```
  console.log
    log right away

      at logInLog (test/mock/mock.unit.test.ts:58:21)

  console.log                                                                                             
    log in two seconds                                                                                    

      at test/mock/mock.unit.test.ts:65:48
```

I'll leave [my github repo](https://github.com/developerasun/web3-snippets/blob/main/test/mock/mock.unit.test.ts) so that you can check them out.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you test an asynchronous function and don't wait for it to finish. For example the following tests also throws the same error.

```js
function getData() {
  setTimeout(() => console.log("Hello"), 2000);
  return 2;
}
test("should pass", () => {
  expect(getData()).toEqual(2);
});
```

You need to learn how to test asynchronous function properly. Here is a short guide from the jest docs. [Async examples](https://jestjs.io/docs/27.0/tutorial-async)

Comment: The error happens when I have all tests commented out... Merely importing the files with those async functions is causing the Jest to error out like that.

Comment: @BrysonKruk Sadly I can't help you with that as I don't have access to your code. You've to debug the issue yourself. Try testing those functions in another test file in isolation.

Comment: Yeah I'm having trouble describing the problem, no worries. I'm thinking it's a configuration issues, since there's no reason why the test file should be needing access to my DB like this.